# Cleaning list of strings by filtering characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-cleaning

Hello I would like to clean a text file that holds a transcript.

I have copy and pasted a small section of the text file.

```
['he looked in <the wellingtons> [//] the boots .\n',
'<last week> [//] one night a boy and a dog was [*] staring at a jar
,\n', 'at this thing inside , wondering what they can do with it the next
morning .\n',' at the same time <the fr(og)> [//] the thing jumped out that jar .']
```

Retain those words that have either ‘ <’ as prefix or ‘> ’ as suffix but these two
symbols should be removed

for example

`he looked in <the wellingtons> [//] the boots .`
should be changed to
`he looked in the wellingtons [//] the boots .`

i also need to:

Retain those words that have either ‘ (’ as prefix or ‘) ’ as suffix but these two
symbols should also be removed similarly to the < and > but this time i need to keep three symbols
as an exception (.), (..), and (...)

the code i have so far but it's really not working

```
# prefix = '<'
# suffix = '>'
# clean = [' '.join(y for y in x.split(' ') if not (y[0] == '<' and y[-1] == '>') or y in {'<','>'}) for x in text]
# return clean 
# the text here refers to a list of strings 

# for the brackets '(' and ')'
# clean = [' '.join(y for y in x.replace('(','').replace(')','') if not (y[0] == '(' or y[-1] == ')') or y in {'(.)', '(..)', '(...)'}) for x in text]
```

i would really like help on the how to remove '(' and ')' but not for the '(.)', '(..)', '(...)'

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    # Function for retrieving data into a list from your .txt file
def get_data(filename):
    # Open file in read mode
    with open(f"{filename}", "r") as f:
        # Reads data into a new list called raw_data with an item for every line
        raw_data = f.readlines()
    return raw_data


def clean(data_to_clean):
    # Removes < and >
    first_clean = [line.replace("<", "").replace(">", "") for line in data_to_clean]
    # Removes ( and ) with restrictions
    # Swap out exceptions with place holders
    swap_out = [linea.replace("(.)", "bdb").replace("(..)", "bddb").replace("(...)", "bdddb") for linea in first_clean]
    # Clean remaining brackets out
    second_clean = [lineb.replace("(", "").replace(")", "") for lineb in swap_out]
    # Swap in exceptions again
    swap_in = [linec.replace("bdb", "(.)").replace("bddb", "(..)").replace("bdddb", "(...)") for linec in second_clean]
    return swap_in

 
print(clean(get_data("mydata.txt")))
```

This relies on not having the collection of letters "bdb", "bddb" & "bdddb" in your transcript but I think that's probably unlikely.

Obviously, mydata.txt would be swapped out for the name of the text file where your transcript is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
lst = ['he looked in <the wellingtons> [//] the boots .\n', '<last week> [//] one night a boy and a dog was [*] staring at a jar,\n', 'at this thing inside , wondering what they can do with it the next morning .\n', 'at the same time <the fr(og)> [//] the thing jumped out that jar .']

for i in lst:
    print(i.replace("<", "").replace(">", ""))
```

Comment: thanks how should i go about doing the ones with '(' and ')' since they have symbols i need to keep?

Comment: No problem. I think you can just do `.replace("\'", "").` For that.

Comment: Retain those words that have either ‘ (’ as prefix or ‘) ’ as suffix but these two symbols should also be removed similarly to the < and > but this time i need to keep three symbols as an exception (.), (..), and (...)

Comment: i was reffering to this one

Comment: This confuses me a bit. What would the output look like?

Comment: Before filtering: a + boy an(d) a dog h(ad) (.)
After filtering: a + boy and a dog had (.)